# Why I see IP in traceroute not in ifconfig, netstat etc

Tags: linux, ip-address

If I issue `traceroute` I see my server IP (213.79.101.145):

```
traceroute to google.com (108.177.14.138), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  213.79.101.145 (213.79.101.145)  10.660 ms  10.630 ms  10.655 ms
...
15  * * lt-in-f138.1e100.net (108.177.14.138)  19.682 ms
```

But if I issue `route -n` I don't see it:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.60.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-3401d68d5001
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-ca69b5732844
172.24.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-34a7a87f6474
172.25.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-5eefb7a364c3
192.168.6.0     192.168.26.200  255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.15.0    192.168.26.200  255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.26.200  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.51.0    192.168.60.168  255.255.255.0   UG    100    0        0 eno1
192.168.60.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
```

Neither `ss` nor `netstat` nor `ifconfig` show it.
Why?

P.S. If you need an additional information I`ll try to give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`213.79.101.145` will be the wan address of your router and the first hop with its lan address being `192.168.60.1`. I assume your server is also the router and that it is using PPPoE to get its wan IP address. I also assume you are with the Russian ISP `COMCOR`. Alternatively, That IP address is at the other end of the PPP link within your ISP.